# Regex to extract the string between 2 occurrence of a character then replace it with another character

Tags: regex, regex-group

Is it a way using Regex to extract the string between a 2 occurrence of a character then replace it with another character. I know that's a bit tricky but i believe it's possible using Regex .. I just tried many ways but seem not working with me.

What i want to achieve is Extracting from this string:

```
 TestNumQ_RY_5100001_OS35QWE_20190702-2.ZIP
```

The String between the First and Third _:

```
RY_5100001
```

Then Replace this _ with / so the end result will be:

```
RY/5100001
```

What i can reach until now is using this:

```
(_(.*?)_)([^_]*)
```

Which retrieve only the below string:

```
_RY_5100001
```

But i need it to be:

```
RY_5100001
```

Comment: Looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty  of hints. Also, refer to [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/3832970) post for some basic regex info. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.

Comment: Honestly and after checking most of the answers i can't find similar scenario. I've updated the question

Comment: The best you can do is use a replacing approach, see http://regex101.com/r/2nRHDM/1. You can extract and replace within one regex match operation.

Comment: If you jusf need `RY_5100001` use a mere `_([^_]*_[^_]*)_` and grab Groul 1 value. There may be other solutions but they all depend on the environment where you are using the regex.

Comment: return string.match(/[^_]*_([^_]*_[^_]*)_.*/)[1];// works in chrome interpreter

Comment: Regex doesn't "do" anything except match. To *alter* a string you need code - please add the tag of the tool/language you're using to the question.